# datatable brakes when adding horizontal scrolling + fixed column

Tags: jquery, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have datatable with horizontal scrolling where the first 2 column should be with fixed without scrolling

the html code for this is the following

```
<table class="table display nowrap">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>e</th>
        <th>f</th>
        <th>g</th>
        <th>h</th>
        <th>i</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the jquery code is

```
    $('.table').DataTable( {
          "searching": false ,  
          "paging": false ,
          fixedColumns: {
             leftColumns: 1
          },         
          scrollX: true,
    });
```

So when I run the combination of this 2 codes using the datatable library the result is the following

[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MpuU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the problem as you reported. Below is the code I have tried. It seems to be satisfied with what you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DataTable demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */
        th, td {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('.table').DataTable( {
                scrollY:        "600px",
                scrollX:        true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging:         false,
                fixedColumns:   {
                    leftColumns: 1,
                    // rightColumns: 1
                }
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table display nowrap">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
        <th>e</th>
        <th>f</th>
        <th>g</th>
        <th>h</th>
        <th>i</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a data</td>
        <td>b data</td>
        <td>c data</td>
        <td>d data</td>
        <td>e data</td>
        <td>f data</td>
        <td>g data</td>
        <td>h data</td>
        <td>i data</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully, this would help you.

Comment: So it only works if I have 13 fields or more 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA7PX.png this is what happens if I have less https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGAJv.png

Comment: Please provide the full version of your code to ease reproduction the issue. I believe the root cause comes up from other places which you don't mention here.